# How to hide obj folder from WPF project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, workspace

I don't know why but since yesterday I have the obj folder that appears in white in my wpf project workspace and I don't know how to hide it. This directory contains the g.i.cs file generated from .xaml file.

Does anyone knows how to hide it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the `Show All Files` icon in the Solution Explorer window:

[image]

It shows/hides the files which are in the project folder but not included in the project itself.